# Run an automatic test on Android with Appium + TestNG + Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium, testng, appium

I'm a beginner with automatic tests and Appium specifically, and I'm trying to a test (for android).

I downloaded:

1. **Appium** - ran the server
2. **Android emulator** (Android Virtual Device Manager)
3. **TestNG**

The purpose of the test is adding a contact to the contact list.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

**The test:**

```
package com.appium;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

public class One {

    private AppiumDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //driver.launchApp();

        // set up appium
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus5");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformV01ersion", "4.1.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage",
            "com.example.android.contactmanager");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".ContactManager");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
                capabilities);
    }

    @Test
    public void addContact() {
        WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.name("Add Contact"));
        el.click();
        List<WebElement> textFieldsList = driver
                .findElementsByClassName("android.widget.EditText");
        textFieldsList.get(0).sendKeys("Some Name");
        textFieldsList.get(2).sendKeys("Some@example.com");
        driver.swipe(100, 500, 100, 100, 2);
        driver.findElementByName("Save").click();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**The EXCEPTION**

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\nadav.miran\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-451394169\testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite setUp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:109)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:39)
    at com.appium.One.setUp(One.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:277)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.auth.Credentials
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@517ceb9b: 13 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@37610393: 7 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@54fba1ac: 0 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@9e12aac: 34 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 0 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@61ed627d: 29 ms
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what the problem is. Exception - please provide the stack. Scenario doesn't work - please explain in what part.

Comment: **Can I add a long text?**
This is the beginning of my error:
_FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite setUp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials_

Comment: You can edit your question

Comment: I added the error, do you know why it could appear?

Comment: I downloaded new .Jar files, but is seems to be like there are still many more missing. is this the real problem? missing these .Jar files?

Comment: Yes I think the problem this is missing jars.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following dependency to your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also please 
download the Selenium-server-standalone.jar from [here](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar) and add to the class path.
Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047437/noclassdeffound-error-during-selenium-webdriver-appium-android-automation) for more details.

Comment: Could you please share you pom file?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error.

It occurred as I pressed the 'run' button in Eclipse but the correct way to run a TestNG test suite is as follows:

```
Right Click on testng.xml
Run as > TestNG Suite
```

I understand this is an old question however I hope this helps